# Why does my for loop only iterate through 1 block blob eventhough there are 2 in the blob container?

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

Hi I'm new to programming and have been working with azure-storage-blob and python for a project that I've been working on. I trying to get a specific index from the blob path so that I can contain it in a variable and use it later on in a csv file, but when I try to iterate through the blobs it only gives back 1 block blob instead of 2. Any idea on why this is or what the problem with my code is?

```
def read_proces_blobcontainer(): 
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    for blob in blob_list: 
        blobname = blob.name 
        path_elements = blobname.split("/")
        projectcode = (path_elements[0])
    print('Projectcode', projectcode)

read_proces_blobcontainer()
```

The output is as follows: Projectcode 00000

These are the blobs in the container which I'm trying to pull the data from:

[Blobs that I'm trying to iterate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw4Ll.png)

Comment: your print statement is outside the loop, so it will only print the last projectcode

Comment: Thank you dzang! Do you mind if I have follow up question? If I put the print statement inside the for loop this time it's going over all of the individual blobs and gives me back thousands of blobs that I don't want to use... I only want the first index of each of the blobs for the folder name... So the output would be: Projectcode 000-0000 and Projectcode 00000.

Comment: Nvm I got the answer to my question. I just appended all the values to a list and removed the duplicates from the with: list(set(list_name)).

Comment: Hi, @YagilElias. Could you mind post an answer and accept it for other community members to benefit from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pamela Peng.

This is the code I used for removing any duplicates within the list that I originally had. I pulled the names of the file paths, split them and dumped them into an empty list. After that you can clean it up with list(set(your_list))

```
def create_list():
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
the_list = []
for blob in blob_list:
    blobname = blob.name
    path_elements = blobname.split("/")
    projectcode = (path_elements[0])
    the_list.append(projectcode)
    #this function below gives you a list back without the duplicates
    the_list = list(set(the_list))
return(the_list)
```